# Options for an embedded "Trace/Debug" Tool

Tags: embedded, printf, trace

I know there a lot of tools out there for embedded system debugging or tracing. But I have a more specific use case:

1. The least amount of extra hardware. Best if it would go through: ethernet / can or  JTAG
2. Live feed of data - not storing data for later analyzing
3. Easy but powerful graphical visualization of live data (like a gauge, bar or plot)
4. easy to use in source code - like using the printf style of code debugging

Hope you have some ideas for sw tools

thank you very much!

Comment: What system are you dealing with?  Some chips have sophisticated trace hardware that can support streaming massive amounts of debug info during execution.  If not, you can use UART for printing or GPIOs (viewed on oscope or logic analyzer) if printing is too slow.

Answer (score 3):

Typically when I start building an embedded system I use the UART as a "system console" to output diagnostic data using printf. You can also add a menu interface that responds to specific commands.

If the embedded system you are creating has a serial interface in the requirements you could use it. If not, simple TTL to USB converters are available.